# error 503: Can't deploy rails 3 app with apache + thin (bitnamy ruby stack)

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, thin

As you'll notice, I'm a bit of a noob on Rails. Here's the thing

I have a EC2 Bitnami RubyStack AMI running. I'm trying to deploy the sample project to be sure I'm doing the right thing, but I'm not getting anywhere at all. I just get a 503 error

I'm following bitnami's docs [on thin + apache](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_RubyStack#Using_Apache_with_Thin)

Here are my files:

the httpd.conf I include in the main httpd.conf

```
Alias /sample "/home/bitnami/stack/projects/sample/public"
<Directory "/home/bitnami/stack/projects/sample/public">
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

ProxyPass /sample balancer://appcluster
ProxyPassReverse /sample balancer://appcluster
<Proxy balancer://appcluster>
   BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3000/sample
   BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001/sample
</Proxy>
```

the thin.yml file

```
chdir: /opt/bitnami/projects/sample
environment: production
address: 127.0.0.1
port: 3000
timeout: 30
log: log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 512
require: []
wait: 30
servers: 2
prefix: /sample
daemonize: true
```

I'm able to start and stop apache, but thin does not stop correctly though. When I try to stop thin, I get this output

```
/opt/bitnami/projects/sample$ sudo thin -C config/thin.yml stop
Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3000 ... 
Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3000.pid
Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3001 ...
```

I've tried to use nginx as well, without any luck unfortunately.

*EDIT:* This answers the comment below. Apache is started and thin is too, but the latter does not stop.

```
/opt/bitnami/projects/sample$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80
/opt/bitnami/projects/sample$ sudo thin -C config/thin.yml startStarting server on 127.0.0.1:3000 ... 
Starting server on 127.0.0.1:3001 ... 
/opt/bitnami/projects/sample$ sudo thin -C config/thin.yml stop
Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3000 ... 
Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3000.pid
Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3001 ... 
Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3001.pid
```

Comment: That means `thin` is not running. Try starting it first, before you stop it.

Comment: Well, could it mean that thin it's not starting even thought the console output shows it supposedly did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll answer my own question (partly).

I didn't know that it was necessary to add the thin gemfile to the Gemfile and If I'm not too burned it's not mention on the tutorials. I added it and the 503 went away. now i have a "Not Found: /" message but that's a different question